# excluding spring jars from spring-data maven dependency

Tags: maven, spring-data

I'm including spring-data in my pom.xml like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

However it includes a bunch of older Spring 3.2.8 jar files that I don't want bundled. Do I need to put exclusions for the 7 or so spring jars to not be included?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask for the reason you want to exclude the dependencies? Without them being present entirely, the library is not going to work (which is why we declare them as dependency in the first place). If it's just about a version upgrade (e.g. using Spring 4 instead of 3.x) the recommended way is not to exclude the transitive dependencies but declare the dependencies locally in the correct version. This can be done using the Spring BOM (documented [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-rc2-available) (replace version with the one you need).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set exclusions. You can either set all of them individually or if you want to exclude all  transitive Spring dependencies that come with Spring Data you may use a wildcard.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Maven will log a warning because that feature will only be supported in upcoming Maven versions even though it's been there for years.